# Configure Web Deploy Publishing - Unable to establish a connection to the MySQL database using the supplied connection string

Tags: mysql, wordpress, iis, webmatrix

I’m am trying to use Microsoft WebMatrix version 3 to create and publish a WordPress site to an IIS 8.0 server.

I have created the WordPress site from the WebMatrix App Gallery and as part of this process MySQL has been installed locally on my PC.

I have configured the IIS server for Web Deploy. I have created a website in IIS, I would like to publish my new wordpress site to. I also created a remote database on another server which has MySQL server installed. As part of the publish process, I would like the local database to get published to this remote database. As of now, it is an empty database with a valid username and password.

From within IIS, when I create the publish settings file I get the following error:

"Unable to establish a connection to the MySQL database using the supplied connection string. Would you like to add the connection string to the XML settings file"

I click save and proceed.

When I use this settings file to validate the connection inside Web Matrix. I get the following error.

"The remote server connection succeeded, but Microsoft WebMatrix cannot access databases."

Related info. I have verified that my remote database is available by connecting to it directly from within Web Matrix. The port 3306 is open. I don't know what else I need. Stumped for several days now :-(

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We're stumped too, since you haven't shared any useful details, like your actual connection string and/or code.

Comment: Here's my connection string: Server=###;Database=wordpress794;uid=wordpressuser794;Pwd=wordpressuser794;

Comment: Is there anything else I should share?

Comment: @Najila August Did you fix the problem? I am having the same issue.